# How to add a scrollable div inside snap-content which is fixed?

Tags: angularjs, scroll

I use the module angular-snap to adding a menu to my app like this:

```
<snap-content>
    <div ui-view='header'></div><br/><br/>
    <div ui-view='content'></div>
</snap-content>

<snap-drawer>
    Menu
</snap-drawer>
```

And my ui-view (content):

```
<div class="content-padded">

    <div class="">
        <center><h4>Accueil</h4></center>
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is I want to put a scrollable div inside my snap-content. And, I don't want the snap-content will become scrollable.

I have the following image to help you to understand what is my problem:

[image]

The three elements in the picture are in snap-content, but only the blue div have to scrollable.

Thank you in advance for your help and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found is :

- putting the snap-content "scrollable"
- putting the divs I want outsdide the scroll "fixed"
- putting a "top" and a "margin-top" in order to have the scroll under my others components.

If somebody have another method, it will be with pleasure.